# How to constrain type of generic extension

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to extend a specific class (say WPF's StackPanel). Let's call this extension MyGenericPanel. I guess its declaration should be:

```
class MyGenericPanel : StackPanel
```

But... if I want this extension to hold variable type of reference (say T) declaration would become:

```
class MyGenericPanel<T> : StackPanel
```

Now what if I want to restrict T to be of type Identifiable... where Identifiable is another class.

```
class MyGenericPanel<T> where T: Identifiable, StackPanel
```

complains that StackPanel should come first... if I put

```
class MyGenericPanel<T> where T: StackPanel, Identifiable
```

the compiler complains Identifiable should come before StackPanel.

Bottomline:

1. MyGenericPanel extends StackPanel
2. T is an extension of Identifiable
3. MyGenericPanel has no XAML definition... It is C# code-only.

How can I do this?... (or, can it be done?)

Comment: The whole thing becomes much clearer when you just always put the generic type constraint on its own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now what if I want to restrict T to be of type Identifiable... where
>   **Identifiable is another class**

well if `Identifiable` and `StackPanel` are  both classes than it can't work because putting 2 class type contraints would mean multiple inheritance , something that's not allowed in C#. That's why the complier complains about your constraints .

If you mean to have your `MyGenericPanel<T>` extend the functionality of `StackPanel` and restrict `T` to be of type `Identifiable` , then following would work :

```
class MyGenericPanel<T> : StackPanel where T : Identifiable
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much. I wanted to restricted the type T to be an Identifiable, while MyGenericPanel<T> is an extension of StackPanel

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confusing the specfication of the base class with the generic type constraint:

```
 class MyGenericPanel<T> : StackPanel where T: Identifiable
```

The class that comes after `MyGenericPanel<T> :` is the base class, the class after `where T:` is the generic type constraint

Answer (score 2):

`MyGenericPanel` extends `StackPanel`

`T` is an extension of `Identifiable`

translated into

```
class MyGenericPanel<T> : StackPanel where T : Identifiable
```